# use that colname to remove the entire column of another dataframe in a programming a sequence of steps

Tags: r

I need some help

I'm programming a sequence of steps (repeat{;;;;;; if();{break}}

I get a colname by >names(df1)[1]
Now I want to use that colname to remove the entire column of another dataframe

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your new dataframe is `df2`

```
columnNames <- names(df1)[1]
df2[,!colnames(df2) %in% columnNames]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `setdiff` to find the column names that are not matching with the first column names of 'df1'

```
 subset(df2, select = setdiff(names(df2), names(df1)[1]))
```

Comment: Thank you both for the help. It went well with " setdiff " .